# SQL Server 2000 stored procedure get unique number from unique ID row avoiding concurrent request issues

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using a central SQL Server 2000 database I have a table called `UNIQUE_ID_COUNTER`. Using the following table structure this holds several rows maintaining the unique ID's assigned to different types of object forwarded to a further system.

```
UNIQUE_ID INT,
NAME VARCHAR(MAX)

234, "APPLES"
189, "PEARS"
...
```

Each time the stored procedure is called from a client the `UNIQUE_ID` is selected via `NAME` and then incremented by 1.

As we have many high request clients in some fringe cases where multiple clients make this request at the same time we are getting multiple `UNIQUE_ID`'s with the same number.

How can I avoid this but still ensure the stored procedure returns the correct value and increments the `UNIQUE_ID` column?

Your help would be most appreciated! :)

Comment: Simple: let the **database** handle all those pesky detail by using a `INT IDENTITY` column - then you'll never have duplicates, you don't need to worry about incrementing your counter - everything's handled for you.

Comment: Nice one marc_s i knew i was over thinking this :)

Answer (score 0):

The preferred and recommend solution is pretty simple: let the database handle all those pesky detail by using a `INT IDENTITY` column.

Then you'll never have duplicates, you don't need to worry about incrementing your counter - everything's handled for you.